# WPF/Catel :The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

Tags: catel

When I check out the latest source from one of the sample projects of Catel (Logviewer/CsvTextEditor) and I build my solution. 
I get a lot of build errors.

All of these error are related to one error:

> The name `'InitializeComponent'` does not exist in the current context.

I've both tried to build the solution in Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.11) as well as Jetbrains Rider.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the libraries require .net core 3.0 (see https://github.com/dotnet/core-sdk) and might require VS 2019 prerelease.